# Prove that : $\lvert s_n - \frac \pi 4\rvert \le \frac 1 {2n+1}$, where $s_n = \sum^{n-1}_{j=0} \frac {(-1)^j} {2j+1}$

Tags: calculus, integration, sequences-and-series, definite-integrals, pi

> Prove (Leibniz' series): $|s_n - \frac \pi 4| \le \frac 1 {2n+1}, \forall n \in \mathbb N$ where $s_n = \sum^{n-1}_{j=0} \frac {(-1)^j} {2j+1} = 1 - \frac 1 3 + \frac 1 5$ ...

To prove the result $\sum^{\infty}_{j=0} \frac {(-1)^j} {2j+1} = \frac \pi 4$ known as Leibniz' series, I've already proved:

(1) $\int^1_0 \frac 1 {1+x^2} dx = s_n + (-1)^n \int^1_0 \frac {x^{2n}} {1+x^2} dx, \forall n \in \mathbb N$

(2) $0 \le \int^1_0 \frac {x^{2n}} {1+x^2} dx \le \frac 1 {2n+1}, \forall n \in \mathbb N$

I'm now asked to prove $\forall n \in \mathbb N : |s_n - \frac \pi 4| \le \frac 1 {2n+1}$, which can be used to prove that $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \sum^{n-1}_{j=0} \frac {(-1)^j} {2j+1} = \frac \pi 4$.

To be honest I've no idea how to relate $s_n$ to $\frac \pi 4$ - There must be some relation in terms of (1) and (2) ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general, if $a_n>0$, $a_n\to 0$ and $a_n$ decreasing then the series 
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{n-1} a_n,
$$
converges (not necessarily absolutely), say to $s$, and
$$
s_{2n-1}<s_{2n+1}<s<s_{2n+2}<s_{2n},
$$
where $s_n=\sum_{k=1}^n (-1)^{k-1}a_k$.
In particular,
$$
s_n-s\quad\text{and}\quad s_{n+1}-s,
$$
have different signs. This implies that
$$
\lvert s-s_{n-1}\rvert<a_n.
$$
In our case
$$
\frac{\pi}{4}-s_n=\int_0^1\frac{dx}{1+x^2}-s_n=(-1)^n\int_0^1\frac{x^{2n}\,dx}{1+x^2}
$$
and since $\int_0^1\frac{x^{2n}\,dx}{1+x^2}\le\frac{1}{2n+1}$, then

$$
\left\lvert \tfrac{\pi}{4}-s_{n}\right\rvert<\frac{1}{2n+1},
$$
which implies that
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty} s_n=\frac{\pi}{4}.
$$

Comment: Thanks, but still how do I show $s_{n-1}\rightarrow \frac \pi 4$ ? I understand your point that we have an alternating series.

Comment: You know that $\frac d{dx}\tan x=1+\tan^2 x$. Thus you also know that $\frac d{dx}\arctan x=\frac1{1+x^2}$. By integrating both sides you see that $\arctan x=\sum(-1)^{k}\frac{x^{2k+1}}{2k+1}$, and on the left side, $\arctan(1)=\frac\pi4$ since $\tan\frac\pi4=1$.

Comment: Thank you. But the main part of the solution is the quantitative statement of the Leibniz theorem as used in this answer, up to the point where (shifting the index) $$\lvert s-s_{n}\rvert<a_{n+1}=\frac1{2n+3}\le a_n=\frac1{2n+1}.$$ The calculation from "In our case..." is even a second, independent solution.

Comment: Thanks Smyrlis. If I knew that the integral of $1/(x^2 +1)$ was equal to $\pi/4$, it would have been a whole lot easier.